# How to add a number of strings as items in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I guess this is a pretty simple task for a "for-loop" but I can't get my head around it. Basically I want the loop to perform this:

```
pop1 = (
    [fitness[0][1]] * fitness[0][0] +
    [fitness[1][1]] * fitness[1][0] + 
    [fitness[2][1]] * fitness[2][0] + 
    [fitness[3][1]] * fitness[3][0]
)
```

BUT for a "N" number of times. I've gotten to this so far but can't get the addition in. Fitness[i][1] is a string and fitness[i][0] is a int.

```
pop1 = []

for i in range(0,popnb):
  x = fitness[i][1]
  y = fitness[i][0]
  z = [x]*y
  pop1.append(z)
```

I guess the answer is not far away, but all help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building one long list; you want to *extend* the `pop1` list rather than append:

```
pop1 = []

for i in range(popnb):
    x = fitness[i][1]
    y = fitness[i][0]
    z = [x] * y
    pop1.extend(z)
```

You could use `pop1 += z` too.

If `popnb` is the length of `fitness`, just loop over `fitness` directly:

```
pop1 = []

for f in fitness:
    pop1 += [f[1]] * f[0]
```

You could use `itertools` function to do the repeating and chaining:

```
from itertools import repeat, chain

pop1 = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(f[1], f[0]) for f in fitness))
```

Comment: Haha thanks a lot for the quick help! It worked! Now i know a bit more about lists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every list inside fitness has 2 values, you can use list comprahension:
`pop1 = [y for x, y in fitness for _ in range(x)]`
For example:

```
fitness = [[8, 10], [8, 3], [5, 8], [5, 1], [2, 10]]
pop1 = [y for x, y in fitness for _ in range(x)]
#pop1 is equal to:
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 10, 10]
```